# Unable to add picture with url parameters on Facebook feed dialog (Direct URL)

Tags: facebook, url, parameters, dialog, feed

I was wondering how could I add parameters to my picture URl on this example:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=...&link=...&picture=www.blablabladotcom?parameter1=1&parameter2=2&name=...&caption=...&description=...&redirect_uri=...

I tried with %26 encoding and picture doesn't show up.
What is strange is that when I try %26 on the redirect_uri parameter, it works fine.
Any tips about this one??

Comment: The URL I try to add is a long Google Maps Static API URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode all the parts properly (example Java Script code below):

```
var _FBAPPID = "xxxxxxxxxx", // your app ID (mandatory)
    _name = "name",
    _text = "text",
    _link = "link",
    _picture = "http://cdn2.insidermonkey.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/facebook4-e1349213205149.jpg", // some google image - replace it
    _caption = "caption",
    _redirect_uri = "http://google.com" // this URL must be from within the domain you specified in your app's settings

var _params = "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(_name)
    + "&description=" + encodeURIComponent(_text)
    + "&link=" + encodeURIComponent(_link)
    + "&picture=" + encodeURIComponent(_picture)
    + "&caption=" + encodeURIComponent(_caption)
    + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(_redirect_uri);

var _href = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" + _FBAPPID + _params + "&display=touch";
```

I have also added `display=touch` because I'm using direct URL only for mobile devices.

Source is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).